# Fixing a systemd service 203/EXEC failure (no such file or directory) while starting nodepool-launcher on centos 7

Tags: centos

I am trying to start nodepool-launcher on centOs 7 so that i can run Zuul API gateway management. Initially, I got this error:

```
Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/nodepool-launcher.service: No such file or directory.
```

I created a file named nodepool-launcher.service in /usr/bin directory. The file contains:

```
[Service]
ExecStart= /bin/bash /usr/bin/nodepool-launcher.service
```

Now, I have this error:

```
[root@mypc ~]# systemd-analyze verify nodepool-launcher.service
nodepool-launcher.service has more than one ExecStart= setting, which is only allowed for Type=oneshot services. Refusing.
Error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Unit is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.
Failed to create nodepool-launcher.service/start: Invalid argument
nodepool-launcher.service: command /usr/bin/nodepool-launcher is not executable: No such file or directory
```

I have followed [this](https://zuul-ci.org/docs/zuul/howtos/nodepool_install.html) documentation for installing and configuring nodepool.

Any suggestions to overcome this problem are most welcome.

Comment: `bash /usr/bin/nodepool-launcher.service` would fail, since `/usr/bin/nodepool-launcher.service` is not a shell script. 

However, unit files are not located under /usr/bin, so that `systemctl analyze` doesn't analyze this file but a file under `/etc/systemd` or `/usr/lib/systemd`. Why do you try to create the unit file under /usr/bin? Also share the output of `systemctl cat nodepool-launcher`.

Comment: Sure. Here is the output:
```
# /etc/systemd/system/nodepool-launcher.service
[Unit]
Description=Nodepool Launcher Service
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
# Options to pass to nodepool-launcher.
Group=nodepool
User=nodepool
RuntimeDirectory=nodepool
ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/nodepool-launcher
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

# /etc/systemd/system/nodepool-launcher.service.d/centos.conf
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nodepool-launcher
```

Guess I need to remove the extra ExecStart in centos.conf.

Comment: @berndbausch i read a few answers in which they overcame ExecStart spawning 203 errror by adding /bin/bash in the .service file just at the beginning of ExecStart=. Therefore, i created that file. But now, i have deleted it. The only error that i have is :
`
failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-01-18 13:24:11 IST; 30s ago
  Process: 26063 ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/bin/nodepool-launcher (code=exited, status=127)
 Main PID: 26063 (code=exited, status=127)

`

Comment: I don't know enough about Zuul to be certain, but most probably `/usr/bin/nodepool-launcher` is not a shell script either. Which would explain the failure. Remove the /bin/bash.

Comment: @berndbausch Really appreciate your help. I simply removed /bin/bash and put /usr/local/bin/nodepool-launcher in both .service and centos.conf files. Now, it is up and running. Thank you very much for your help. If you want me to accept your answer, I will be more than happy to do so.

Comment: I moved my comment to an answer to reap your appreciation points :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `centos.conf` file causes trouble, I would simply remove it and replace `/usr/local/bin/nodepool-launcher` in the unit file with `/usr/bin/nodepool-launcher`. After that, don't forget to run `systemctl daemon-reload` to tell systemd that the configuration has changed.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, if anyone encounters this issue, these three steps helped me:

Note: Please replace 'nodepool-launcher' with your package/module.

1. Use this command `locate nodepool-launcher.service`. From the output list, you can easily figure out in which directory the service is actually present. In my case, it was `/usr/local/bin/nodepool-launcher`.
2. Check the unit file and make sure ExecStart points to this directory. You may read the content using `systemctl cat {directory location}/nodepool-launcher.service` and edit using ```vi {directory location}/nodepool-service. Please remove /bin/bash or anything as such if present in case it is not shell script.
3. If a .conf file is present, make sure that ExecStart in this file points to the same directory as above.

In my case, the .conf file had ExecStart pointing to `/usr/bin/nodepool-launcher` which i changed to `/usr/local/bin/nodepool-launcher` and it ran like a charm. Hope it helps someone.